# How do I find the operating point when wanting to linearize the differential equation $ 10\ddot{y}(t) + \dot{y}(t) = u^{2}(t) $?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, linearization

I have a dynamic system with input $u$ and output $y$ that is described by the following ODE

$$ 10\ddot{y}(t) + \dot{y}(t) = u^{2}(t) $$

that I want to linearize around $u=1$ and determine its transfer function $G(s) = \dfrac{Y(s)}{U(s)}$.

---

I start with assigning $x_{1} = y$ and $x_{2} = \dot{y}$ which gives

$$ \begin{aligned} \dot{x_{1}} &= \dot{y} = x_{2} \\ \dot{x_{2}} &= \ddot{y} = \frac{u^{2}(t) - x_{2}}{10} \end{aligned} $$

Now to linearize I use that

$$ \Delta\dot{x} = A\Delta x + B\Delta u $$

$$ \Delta y = C\Delta x + D\Delta u $$

$$ \Delta x = x - x_{0},\ \Delta u = u - u_{0} $$

where $A = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}$ and $B = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u_{i}}$ where both are evaluated at our operating point $(x_{0}, u_{0})$. C and D are obtained in similar ways but differentiating $g$ (corresponding to the equation for y) and not $f$. So we need to find out operating point. We know that $u_{0} = 1$ and to get $x_{0}$ we can set $\dot{x}=0$ and
solve for $x_{10}$ and $x_{20}$. Though this is where I am having problems. Obtaining $x_{10}$ is simple enough, from our assignment $x_{1} = y$ we simply get that $x_{10} = y_{0}$. What is weird is that I am getting conflicting answers for $x_{20}$, see below.

$$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \dot{x_{1}} &= x_{20} = 0 \\
        \dot{x_{2}} &= \frac{u^{2}_{0} - x_{20}}{10} = 0 \implies x_{20} = u_{0}^{2}
    \end{split}
\end{equation} $$

So is the operating point $(x_{10}, x_{20}, u_{0}) = (y_{0}, 0, 1) $ or $(x_{10}, x_{20}, u_{0}) = (y_{0}, u^{2}_{0}, 1) $?

---

After getting the operating point I would continue and obtain the following matrices

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -\frac{1}{10} \end{bmatrix}, \qquad B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \frac{2u\dot{u}}{10} \end{pmatrix}, \qquad C = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad D = 0 $$

Evaluating these at the operating point and plugging into the expression for $\Delta \dot{x}$ and $\Delta y$ yields the linearization. Then to obtain the transfer function I can simply use that

$$ G(s) = C(sI - A)^{-1}B + D $$

All doable as long as I have the operating point, but as mentioned previously I am having trouble finding it.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Why do you need $G (s)$?

Comment: Your system can only have an equilibrium point whenever $u=0$. So, your only equilibrium point in that case is $(x_1,x_2,u)=(y_0,0,0)$ where $y_0$ can be anything. Another issue is that the second entry of the $B$ matrix is $2u_0=0$. So, $B=0$ at the equilibrium point.

Comment: @KBS Hmm, that is interesting. The problem statement I have been given says to linearize around $u=1$, is there something wrong with the problem statement then? If $u_{0} = 0$ then the conflict goes away as we get $x_{2} = 0$ in both cases and not $x_{2} = u_{0}^{2} = 1^{2}$ in one of the cases like I got. That seems good. Also, why is $x_{1}=0$ and not $y_{0}$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I feel like it is clear what I am trying to do, linearize the differential equation around $u=1$ and then obtain it's transfer function $G(s)$. Why I want to do this doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: @NoName123 It is relevant as a lot of questions are actually related to solving a problem in the wrong way. Providing context helps to avoid this and redirect the person in the right direction.

Comment: @KBS Fair enough. In this case there is not much context to go by, it's simply a practice problem related to learning about space-space representations and linearizations of non-linear dynamic systems.

Comment: @NoName123 Also, why is $x_1=0$ and not $y_0$? It has nowhere been said that $x_1=0$. Please provide more context to your question and where this is coming from. Also, make sure that you have written the problem correctly.

Comment: You can linearize around $u=1$ but you will get a constant nonzero term in the linearized dynamics. When linearizing about an equilibrium point, this constant term becomes zero. It comes from the Taylor expansion of the function $f(x,u)$ describing the dynamics $\dot{x}=f(x,u)$. A first-order Taylor expansion about $(x_0,u_0)$ yields $\dot{\tilde{x}}=f(x_0,u_0)+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,u_0)\tilde x+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}(x_0,u_0)\tilde u$.

Comment: @KBS My bad, I read your message as $(x_{1}, x_{2}, u) = (0, 0, 0)$ and not $(y_{0}, 0, 0)$ like you wrote. The problem statement has been written correctly, I can assure you of that. I am not sure what context you want. The practice problem is from a non-english book used for a Control Theory class. The problem statement you see, is the problem statement I got. There is no context saying what dynamic system in particular is being modeled or anything like that.

Comment: Then, there is a problem in the statement of the exercise.

Comment: @NoName123 Your ODE is already linear in state.  Use $v := u^2$ as input instead.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Do you want to expand on this? Perhaps in a full answer?

Answer (score 1):

As $u^2\approx u_0^2+2u_0(u-u_0)$ and $10\ddot y_0+\dot y_0 = u_0^2$ we have

$$
10\ddot y+\dot y = 10\ddot y_0+\dot y_0 +2u_0(u-u_0)
$$

or

$$
10\delta\ddot y+\delta\dot y = 2u_0\delta u
$$

with $\delta y = y - y_0, \ \delta u = u - u_0$ and now we can apply the Laplace transform.

NOTE

With null initial conditions we have $y_0 = u_0^2 t$ and $(y_0, u_0)$ is the operating orbit.